# Disable INFO: fbprophet: Disabling daily seasonality from printing

Tags: python, prophet

Can anyone help in disabling Prophet printing the Info on the terminal each time I train a model. I am training multiple models and each time it print this to the terminal :

```
INFO:fbprophet:Disabling daily seasonality. Run prophet with daily_seasonality=True to override this.
```

I have done a lot of searching and can not find a solution to this problem. Any anyone have a workaround?

Comment: does not daily_seasonality=True or daily_seasonality=False  disable it? if no, could you provide a minimal working example

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Change this code:

```
m = Prophet(holidays=holidays)
```

And add the following:

```
m = Prophet(holidays=holidays, daily_seasonality=True)
```

Comment: this will disable the log, but change what type of seasonality the model uses. Prophet was detecting that there was no daily seasonality, so it disabled it and tells you what its doing with the log.  A better way to disable the log would be `daily_seasonality=False`.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks both. Have aimed to delete the answer, but I can't whilst it is an accepted answer.

Comment: Agree, just enabling the daily seasonality will turn the log off, but change the model composition.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to suppress this annoying message without setting `daily_seasonality=True` in the model is to set the logging level higher than INFO for fbprophet:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('fbprophet').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Update: the current (version 1.1.4. I would guess the change happened at version 1.0) Prophet logger is named 'prophet'. So @Jeremy Tran's answer is correct, but the second line should be updated to:

`logging.getLogger('prophet').setLevel(logging.WARNING)`